# The meaning of "high-fidelity" in the mentioned context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "high-fidelity" in the following context?

> Over millions of years in the fossil record, hominin teeth preserve a
>   **high-fidelity** record of their own growth, development, wear, chemistry
>   and pathology. They yield insights into human evolution that are
>   difficult, if not impossible, to achieve through other sources of
>   fossil or archaeological data. ([Source](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/life-sciences/biological-anthropology-and-primatology/what-teeth-reveal-about-human-evolution?format=PB#fmS35u8gXQuSh7wR.97))

I know the meaning of high-fidelity as it is used in stereophonic businesses. It means highly similar to the real sound. But in the above text, I cannot figure out its meaning.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up "fidelity" in a dictionary?

Comment: Its figurative meaning is pretty much the same as with sound (though possibly derived differently).

Answer (score 1):

"Fidelity" is just another way of saying "Faithful" or "True to its original form." Going from context clues, this passage states that hominin teeth give a high-fidelity record - meaning, they still contain much of the detail that they would have, when the body to which they belong was still alive.